# Excel: how to change Default file option to UTF-8 away from Macintosh file option?

Tags: macos, ms-office, bug, encoding, csv

When I double-click and open a csv file in Excel, the OSX Excel always opens it in Macintosh format destroying the visualisation of UTF-8 files with malformatted umlaut characters such as ö and ä. I want to avoid opening files in OSX Excel in UTF-8 format by manually typing the UTF-8 format with options such as `Import`.

**How can I change the default file option to UTF-8 in OSX so files can be opened in UTF-8, instead of Macintosh format, automatically even in the GUI and Finder?**

Microsoft Excel for Mac: Version 15.30.

OSX: macOS Sierra, Version 10.12.1

**Related questions in Superuser but not focus on OSX**

> 1. [Change default encoding of Excel to UTF-8](https://superuser.com/questions/911369/change-default-encoding-of-excel-to-utf-8)
> 2. [How to set character encoding when opening Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel)

Comment: I don't think you can - you need to use get external data on the data tab.

Comment: What if you make the file look like a UTF8 file first .. [add a BOM to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127436/adding-bom-to-utf-8-files) look for the comment by [@Yaron U](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729673/yaron-u).

Comment: @MrR For importing a (Tab separated) Text File a UTF-8 BOM it works.

Comment: Based on the registry modification described in [the first answer of the first link](https://superuser.com/a/1179248), it might be possible to modify the registry in `/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app/Contens/SharedSupport/Registries/Microsoft Excel.reg` which is an SQLite format registry, but although I can open the database, I don't understand how to add the entry within its structure. Maybe someone else can find out?